# java regular expression for multiple spaces

Tags: java, regex

Can I write a single line regular expression instead of the five lines below?

```
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("[ ]+", " ");
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("(\\r\\n)+", "\r\n");
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("(\\t)+", " ");
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

What's the difference between these regular expressions?

Comment: if would be helpful if you explained what you are trying to achieve - what this code is really trying to do

Comment: See [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)...

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a clear question where the OP doesn't know the answer. That's what SO is for.

Comment: See my answer. You need only two lines and one regex only!

Comment: and now a "close" vote as "too localized". It's not; it's a widely applicable request. (It might be a duplicate, but that's another matter)

Comment: What should happen to two tabs, followed by two spaces? Your regexes will convert them to *two* spaces, not one. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 6):

```
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
```

removes whitespace at the start of the string.

```
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

removes whitespace at the end of the string.

```
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("[ ]+", " ");
```

condenses multiple spaces into a single space.

```
strTestIn =strTestIn.replaceAll("(\\r\\n)+", "\r\n");
```

removes empty lines by replacing adjacent newlines with a single newline.

```
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("(\\t)+", " ");
```

condenses tabs into a single space.

So they all do different things. A combination is possible for those that have the same replacement string:

```
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("^\\s+|\\s+$", "");
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll(" {2,}|\t+", " ");
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("(\r\n)+", "\r\n");
```

You can also clean up and improve the regexes a bit (removing some unnecessary backslashes, and changing the minimum number of spaces to two).